# C# MVC RouteBase routing too many redirects

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

Eu tenho um sistema de todas dinâmico aonde eu pego todos os meus **paths**, **controllers**, **views** e **areas** a partir do **BD**.

Meu problema agora é quando eu tento acessar uma página ele me retorna `too many redirects response`.

O que acontece nessa área é:

- Usuário preenche um formulário;
- O formulário é postado via AJAX e o usuário é redirecionado via Jquery;
- O usuário então faz um agendamento ou visualiza o voucher;

Se o usuário tenta retornar a pagina inicial tanto usando o botão de voltar ou alterando a URl ele cai em um loop de *redirect*, isso ocorre porque nas páginas de agendamento e voucher eu tenho uma verificação de session, se ela for nula eu faço o redirecionamento de volta ao inicio(formulário), esta é a verificação de redirect:

```
if (TempData["LeadID"] == null || Session["UnidadeCE"] == null)
{
    Response.Redirect( HelperMethods.CreateLink( Request.RawUrl.TrimStart( '/' ).Split( '/' )[0] ) );
    Response.End();

    return null;
}
```

Agora, o que é estranho é que quando ele tenta mudar a página o `RouteBase` tenta recuperar as informações desta nova URL e neste momento por algum motivo ele acaba pegando a mesma página, de agendamento, ao invés da página de form e daí começa todo o looping.

O pior é que isto só acontece na primeira vez, por exemplo:

Preenchi o form, cai no agendamento e fui para o voucher, tentei retornar cai em loop, espero e dou um refresh, carrega a pagina normalmente.

Como o código é meio extenso eu coloquei ele em um bin: http://pastebin.com/yTdWKMp4

E tem também os headers dos requests:

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Cache-Control: private, no-store, max-age=1
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Encoding: gzip
Expires: Wed, 25 Nov 2015 19:01:23 GMT
Last-Modified: Wed, 25 Nov 2015 19:01:22 GMT
Etag: ""
Location: /teste-lp
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
X-AspNetMvc-Version: 3.0
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
X-UA-Compatible: IE=Edge,chrome=1
Date: Wed, 25 Nov 2015 19:01:22 GMT
Content-Length: 115

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: private, no-store, max-age=1
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Encoding: gzip
Expires: Wed, 25 Nov 2015 19:02:10 GMT
Last-Modified: Wed, 25 Nov 2015 19:02:09 GMT
Etag: ""
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
X-AspNetMvc-Version: 3.0
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
X-UA-Compatible: IE=Edge,chrome=1
Date: Wed, 25 Nov 2015 19:02:12 GMT
Content-Length: 6852
```

**EDIT**

Depois de muito debug e checagem de vars ( tenho cerca de 6k rotas dentro do pageList ) eu descobri que o problema está sendo na hora de verificar o valor e atualizar a variável.

Na linha 128 do arquivo do pastebin eu recebo uma lista de rotas e procuro dentro dela a rota que me interessa, na linha 167 é o caso do voucher, eu verifico se tem este nome na URL e procuro a rota correta, como esta é uma rota "genérica" para as três áreas ( form, agendamento e voucher ) eu preciso colocar o `Controller` e `Action` que eu quero. Neste momento eu estou atualizando uma variável local, mas acabo atualizando também o parâmetro `pageList`.

Eu também já tentei colocar uma outra variável `pages` dentro do método da linha 128, copiar o `pageList` para ela e depois realizar a busca dentro dela. o `pageList` também acaba sendo atualizado assim como o Cache, linha 202.

O que pode estar gerando isso ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depois de um pouco de pesquisa eu descobri que o meu problema estava na verdade relacionado ao cache do .NET, eu não havia utilizado o método `clone`.

Se o clone não for utilizado o valor copiado de um `Cache` manterá um "link de referência", e com isso quando eu estava editando algumas informações nas rotas ele estava aplicando esta alteração ao cache e com isso caindo em um loop de redirect.

No meu caso acontecia isso porque na para cair na página de agendamento eu preciso alterar o valor da `Action` pois a rota de cadastro é genérica ( mesma rota existente no BD server para o cadastro, agendamento e voucher ), quando eu alterava o valor a rota original ficava sempre apontando para a `Action` Agendamento ao invés da action `Index` e quando caia na verificação de uma Session ele fazia o redirect.

Como expliquei acima, consegui resolver o problema implementando o `Clone` para estes objetos, atualizei o meu doc no PasteBin ( http://pastebin.com/yTdWKMp4 ) caso alguém queira entender como funciona.